# Replace zero array with new values one by one NumPy

Tags: arrays, numpy

I stuck with a simple question in NumPy. I have an array of zero values. Once I generate a new value I would like to add it one by one.

```
arr=array([0,0,0])
# something like this
l=[1,5,10]
for x in l:
     arr.append(x)   # from python logic
```

so I would like to add one by one x into array, so I would get: 1st iteration `arr=([1,0,0])`; 2d iteration `arr=([1,5,0])`; 3rd `arr=([1,5,10])`;

Basically I need to substitute zeros with new values one by one in NumPy (I am learning NumPy!!!!!!). 
I checked many of NumPy options like np.append (it adds to existing values new values), but can't find the right.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to pick up with numpy:

- you can generate the array full of zeros with

  ```
  >>> np.zeros(3)
  array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
  ```
- You can get/set array elements with indexing as with `list`s etc:

  ```
  arr[2] = 7

  for i, val in enumerate([1, 5, 10]):
      arr[i] = val
  ```
- Or, if you want to fill with array with something like a `list`, you can directly use:

  ```
  >>> np.array([1, 5, 10])
  array([ 1,  5, 10])
  ```
- Also, numpy's signature for appending stuff to an array is a [bit different](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html):

  ```
  arr = np.append(arr, 7)
  ```

Having said that, you should just consider diving into [Numpy's own userguide](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.html).